# Encrypted data in a from post -- base64 encode?

Tags: http, encryption, base64

I'm sending some pre-encrypted strings (AES) to a REST API, this is data that has been encrypted by the client. I am storing the data, and never decrypting it on the server side.

I will hand it back to the client later.

My initial thought was to use base64 encoding to ensure the data survives the form post. Is this the correct way to do things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need any special encoding to POST data to a server, as there is no restriction to what characters you can use.

If you choose to send the encrypted data as binary data, you should specify content-type header to be application/octet-stream.

Comment: Thanks. I am using octet-stream and directly form posting, works great.